# How to eliminate audio device transfer function from recording?

Tags: frequency-response, transfer-function

I'm working on a project which requires analysis of filter transfer function of vocal tract. The vocal tract is excited by a source signal that is a frequency sweep. The source signal is provided through an audio device. The device has it's own transfer function which would change the results as expected from the actual transfer function.

I know the transfer function of the device.

Can anyone help me with how should I eliminate the effect of transfer function of the device from the recording in MATLAB?

Comment: De-convolution possibly?